# Ecwid JS API Manage Customer Cart

Tags: jquery, json, api, javascript-objects

I'm trying to use Ecwid's JS API, specifically the Manage Customer Cart's [Add Product](https://api-docs.ecwid.com/reference/ecwidcartaddproduct) and [Remove Product](https://api-docs.ecwid.com/reference/ecwidcartremoveproduct) functions.

It works when I use them separately.

Now, the problem is when trying to reduce the quantity of a product currently in cart. The JS API doesn't have this functionality (or at least I can't find it), so what I'm trying to do is remove the product altogether then re-add the product with one less quantity than it had before.

Say I have this products currently in cart:

```
[
{
    "product": {
        "price": 33,
        "name": "Product 1",
        "id": 101,
        "shortDescription": "1",
        "url": ""
    },
    "quantity": 6
},
{
    "product": {
        "price": 33,
        "name": "Product 2",
        "id": 102,
        "shortDescription": "2",
        "url": ""
    },
    "quantity": 5
},
{
    "product": {
        "price": 33,
        "name": "Product 3",
        "id": 103,
        "shortDescription": "3",
        "url": ""
    },
    "quantity": 9
}
]
```

To increase the quantity of `Product 1` by one.

```
var product = {
    id: 101,
    qty: 1,
    callback: function(success, product, cart, clicked, index) {}
}

Ecwid.OnAPILoaded.add(function() {
    Ecwid.Cart.addProduct(product);
});
```

To reduce the quantity of `Product 1` by one.

```
var product = {
    id: 101,
    qty: 
    callback: function(success, product, cart, clicked, index) {}
}

Ecwid.OnAPILoaded.add(function() {
    Ecwid.Cart.removeProduct(0); // index of Product 1
    Ecwid.Cart.addProduct(product);

    Ecwid.OnCartChanged.add(function(cart){
        Ecwid.Cart.get(function(cart){
            console.log(cart.items);
        }
   });
});
```

Scenario 1:
When I load the page and `increase` the qty, it `WORKS`

Scenario 2:
When I load the page and `increase` the qty then `decrease` the qty, it `WORKS`

Scenario 3:
When I load the page and `decrease` the qty, it `DOESN'T WORK`. I can see 3 items in the console log instead of just 2.

The first log returns only 2 items, which means the product was successfully removed.
The second one returns 3 items, with the removed product being readded, this time with the quantity only 5, meaning the product was successfully readded with one less quantity.
But then a third log is returned, which is similar to the first log. On `Scenario 2`, only 2 logs are returned when i `decrease` the quantity.

Sorry for the long post.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is Harvel, Ecwid by Lightspeed Apps&API team.

Sorry for the late reply! I've taken a look at your code and see that you do not specify the quantity of the product here:

> To reduce the quantity of Product 1 by one.

```
var product = {
    id: 101,
    qty: 
    callback: function(success, product, cart, clicked, index) {}
}
```

I've tried to run such a code in my test store and it didn't work as well, I got an error. Thus, the issue might be here.

On the other hand, when I specified the quantity in the product variable, it worked fine. Here's the code that I used:

```
  var product = {
  id: {productId},
  quantity: 1
};

Ecwid.OnAPILoaded.add(function() {
    Ecwid.Cart.removeProduct(0); // index of Product 1
    Ecwid.Cart.addProduct(product);
});
```

I've run some tests and it worked fine, here's the screencast: https://ecwid.d.pr/vqdl0f.

Kindly try to do it this way, will it work?

Let me know if I got you wrong. Also, feel free to reach out to us at ec.apps@lightspeedhq.com, we will always help.